# How do i set test suite name while using cucumber xml report?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am using cucumber java for my selenium UI testing, here is my feature file

```
@space
Feature: Login
  Background:
    Given Person launched the login page of web
  Scenario: web should accept accounts.dev login credentials
    And person enters valid domain id from line 1
    When Person enters valid Email and Password
    And Person clicks on the Login button
    Then Person should be authenticated
```

for reporting i send the results to testrail so i use the Junit: cucumber-xml to generate xml based report. When i run my test my test suite name is filled with the plugin name like this "io.cucumber.core.plugin.JUnitFormatter" is there a way i can set my test suite name?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="io.cucumber.core.plugin.JUnitFormatter" skipped="0" tests="1" time="4.889">
    <testcase classname="Login" name="Spacecloud should accept accounts.dev login credentials" time="4.724">
        <system-out><![CDATA[Given Person launched the login page of SpaceCloud..........................passed
And person enters valid domain id from line 1...............................passed
When Person enters valid Email and Password.................................passed
And Person clicks on the Login button.......................................passed
Then Person should be authenticated.........................................passed
]]></system-out>
    </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

I tried using the @tags but it didnt work for me.

Comment: The name can't be changed but the latest versions use `name="Cucumber"`.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please tell me this version?

Comment: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#7110---2023-01-12

Comment: It is a bit off topic, but we are developing product called Railflow (https://railflow.io) - it is very flexible tool for exporting test reports into TestRail and works with native cucumber json reports. And we are also open to support customer requirements if they are not yet a part of the product.